# Css style config file for setting program options + parser

Tags: c++, css, configuration, config

**Does there exist an existing config file format that works in the same way as HTML+CSS?**

I would like to specify a config file for some software that uses the css method of declaring properties, i.e. in any order you want, hierarchical, of specific elements/entire types/entire classes, ability to override.

Yaml can override properties, but its unwieldy.

An example of what I'd be looking for

```
programSegment
{
    maxDuration: 1000
}

programFeature1
{
    iterations: 10;
    maxDuration: 30;
}

#specificInstance
{
    iterations: 1000;
}

.instanceType
{
    maxDuration: 10;
}

<programFeature1 id="one" />
<programFeature1 id="specificInstance" />
<programFeature1 id="three" class="instanceType" />
<programSegment>
    <programFeature1 id="four" />
    <programFeature1 id="five" class="instanceType" />
</programSegment>
```

Ideally this would enable me to fire up 5 instances of some feature in my program, each with some differently configured properties according to their id/class/type/parent.

Ideally I'd be able to grab the properties without having to traverse the heirarchy myself.

**Does a different format like this exist? What is it?**

**Are there any generic css/xml parsers for cpp that will work like this?**